# Change section height in WordPress (Shapely Theme)

Tags: css, wordpress

I am playing around with a wordpress site as I'd like to switch from Wix. It is being hosted here: https://globalstudyukbeta2.000webhostapp.com/

I am wondering how I can reduce the space between each section, as there is a lot of empty space. I tried using the CSS editor and looking at the stylesheet but to no avail.

Thanks!
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css in your active theme `style.css`

```
.bg-secondary {
    padding: 30px 0;
}
.widget.shapely_home_parallax {
   height: 335px;
}
```

Comment: This is what I tried earlier, but it didn't seem to make a different. Do you think it could be somehow overridden? :) Thanks for the response!

Comment: where you added this css? i cannot see in style.css

Comment: Ah apologies - perhaps I was just impatient and it took a while to update. For some reason it only changed now for me. Thank you so much!